# foreach for discinct value and multiple result on the same line

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

In a nutshell:
  I want to create a list for students and grades. When I get my sql, I get many     grades for the same student. What I'm trying to do is this:

Student 1  -> Grade 1  -> Grade 1 -> Grade 3 
  Student 2  -> Grade 1  -> Grade 2 -> Grade 3

My sql pulls all the records in the database which is great but how can I get it    to display like this?

SQL is very standard

```
$query_getGradesTr1 = "SELECT gradeID, studentID, grades.examID, grade FROM grades, exams WHERE exams.trackID=1 AND grades.examID=exams.examID";
$getGradesTr1 = mysql_query($query_getGradesTr1, $Site) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getGradesTr1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($getGradesTr1);
$totalRows_getGradesTr1 = mysql_num_rows($getGradesTr1);
```

I thought about using a foreach to go through the results, basically foreach  studentID give me all the grades associated with them and repeat for each students... 
But I get multiple results with same StudentID then another studentID, like this:

Student 1  -> Grade 1 
  Student 1  -> Grade 2 
  Student 1  -> Grade 3 
  Student 2  -> Grade 1 
  Student 2  -> Grade 2 
  Student 2  -> Grade 3

Any suggestions??

Comment: What do you need to do? An array? What is the format of the array you want? Maybe can be `$array[student][grade]` and it contains information? or maybe `$array[student] = array("Grade 1", "Grade 2", "Grade 3")` ? It's very different depending on what you need

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$current_student = NULL;
foreach($totalRows_getGradesTr1 as $each) {
    // Check here is student does not matches to previous student
    if($each->studentID !== $current_student) {
        // If not matches then print, else ignore
        echo "$each->studentID";
    }
    // Assign to check again in next loop
    $current_student = $each->studentID;
    // Always print grade
    echo "-&gt; $each->gradeID";
}
```

Another solution is, twice loop the array and make each studentId as array key assign all grades to the studentID, like:

```
$students_grades = array();
foreach($totalRows_getGradesTr1 as $each) {
    if(!isset($student_grades[$each->studentID]) {
        $student_grades[$each->studentID] = array();
    }
    $student_grades[$each->studentID][] = $each->gradeID;
}

// Then nested loop here and print records
foreach($student_grades as $studentID => $grades) {
    echo "$studentID -&gt; " . implode('-&gt;', $grades) . "\r<br>";
}
```